# ExtJS: Loading store produces "entityType is null" error in browser log

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I'm using a button click to change a store's AJAX proxy URL and then .load()ing with the new URL.

The request is made properly and I see that the response is correct. However, the gridpanel that's supposed to load stays empty (saying "loading...") and the error `entityType is null` appears in the browser log.

It's a cryptic error and have no idea what's wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. In Sencha Architect, I'd created a store of type Ext.data.JsonStore. Deleting it and creating a plain-old Ext.data.Store type solved the problem.